# How do I remove a user from a group?

Tags: users, group

Which command should I use to remove a user from a group in Debian?

When adding a user to a group, it can be done with:

```
usermod -a -G group user
```

However, I could not find a similar command (accepting a group and user as arguments) for removing the user from the group. The closest I could get is:

```
usermod -G all,existing,groups,except,for,group user
```

Is there a command like `usermod OPTION group user` with OPTION an option to make `usermod` (or a similar program) remove the user from group?

Comment: For Fedora users who end up here, man usermod reveals in -G option comments that a listing all current groups wish to be retained IS the way to delete a group.  No -R option with Fedora; you must use Lekensteyn's approach he is trying to avoid.

Comment: `usermode -r USER -G GROUP` works in debian .

Answer (score 614, accepted):

You can use `gpasswd`:

```
# gpasswd --delete user group
```

The new group config will be assigned at the next login. If the user is logged in, the effects of the command aren't seen immediately.

Comment: Perfect thanks! `gpasswd -a user group` for adding the user to the group seems also nicer, especially if a typo has made and the `-a` option gets dropped.

Comment: Is there a way to make the change take effect without having to re-login?

Comment: Interestingly, using this to remove the user from the `nogroup` group (in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), did not really remove the user from the group, even though the command itself succeeded. (It was a `--system` account and there were no logins. I had to remove the account completely and then add it again.)

Comment: It took a whole restart for me to leave the "docker" group, somehow (Ubuntu 22.04). After logout + re-login, the output of "groups" still showed docker, and I could still call docker commands without sudo.

Answer (score 240):

On Debian, the `adduser` package contains a `deluser` program which removes a user from a group if you pass both as arguments:

```
deluser user group
```

If your distribution doesn't have `adduser`, you can edit `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` manually.

```
vigr
vigr -s
```

Comment: I did not know of programs like `vigr` and `vipw`. Very useful in case the manpages are too far away :)

Comment: Alternatively, after modifying `/etc/group` run `grpconv` to update `/etc/gshadow` rather than editing it.

Comment: `sudo deluser jenkins admin`
/usr/sbin/deluser: You may not remove the user from their primary group.

Comment: @JonathanLeaders Every user needs to be in at least one group. Use `usermod` or `vipw` to change the user's primary group. This question was about supplementary groups.

Comment: Nice. There's also the simpler `adduser $user $group` command instead of the `usermod -x -y -z -...`.

Answer (score 96):

```
usermod -G "" username
```

removes all secondary/supplementary groups from *username*, leaving them as a member of only their primary group.
this worked in Solaris 5.9

Comment: And this seems to be the best way to force the secondary groups to *any* list of groups, excluding all unlisted groups.

Comment: if execute it being not the root, to see the updated group list with the command 'groups' you need to relogin.

Comment: Note the question asked to remove the user from "a group" not all groups.

Answer (score 21):

This is the “old school” approach...

Most *nix systems maintain group information into a plain text file [`/etc/group`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/group.5.html), where

- each line contains the fields

  - group_name
  - password
  - GID, and
  - user_list

  delimited by the `:` character.
- the user_list field is a list of user names, separated by commas.

Now suppose you want to remove a user named `thisuser`
from a group named `thatgroup`.  Start by backing up `/etc/group`,
then use the editor of your preference *with su privileges*
to edit the file `/etc/group`
and remove the `thisuser` reference from the `thatgroup` line entry, e.g.,

original line is something like this:

`thatgroup:x:1274:someuser,thisuser,anotheruser`

after editing should be left like this:

`thatgroup:x:1274:someuser,anotheruser`

As with all the other answers, this will not affect the user's current session(s), if any (i.e., if the user is currently logged in). 
The change will take effect the next time the user logs in.

Comment: `vigr` was already mentioned for editing `/etc/group` manually. My manual pages says that user names are separated by commas, not by colons. Rebooting is not necessary, you just need to re-login (or use `newgrp`).

Comment: To assist any non-Debian users hitting these shores looking for clues... this may be enough for Debian as per the scope of OP's question, but if you were using this for a *BSD OS, you would need to modify the plaintext file here as mentioned, then issue a pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd to actually put that list into use.

Answer (score 3):

The command to add a group to a user:

```shell
usermod -aG group user
```

The command to remove a group from a user is:

```shell
usermod -rG group user
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command on SUSE distributions
(and, apparently, *no others*).

```
usermod -R group user_name
```

where *`group`* is the group that you want to remove the user from
and *`user_name`* the user that you want to remove from the group.
For example,

```
usermod -R root imnottheroot
```

Comment: What package provides your usermod binary? I'm asking to find out the version, as mine from shadow-utils-4.1.4.3 does not provide the -R option.

Comment: My shadow 4.1.5.1-5 package (Arch Linux) does have an `-R` option, but that means something else. It's not Linux I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. The manpage is saying that `-R` is: "-R, --root CHROOT_DIR
           Apply changes in the CHROOT_DIR directory and use the configuration files from the CHROOT_DIR directory.
"

Comment: The only things sort of related I could find was [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/usermod-1m.html) oracle manpage, but that's still not about the same thing, so this answer should maybe be removed.

Comment: `sudo usermod -R admin jenkins`
usermod: invalid chroot path 'admin'

Answer (score 1):

You can remove users from the group by executing usermod command without -a option.
Example, by executing

```
usermod -G group1 username
```

will add the user to the group1, and will remove it from any other groups where it is. Remember, you can keep users in various groups by listing the group's names, separated with a comma.

Comment: This information has been  presented multiple times already.

Comment: NOTE: it's a opposite which made `username` only in this `group1`

Answer (score 0):

On OpenBSD

```
usermod -S "" user
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pw groupmod "groupname|gid" -d "username|uid"
```

A solution if you are using CSH, for whatever reason.

Answer (score -1):

Consider:

- username: `abc2`
- group name: `newgroup11`
- Task: Removing user `abc2` from group `newgroup11`

```
[root@home1 ~]# groups abc2
abc2 : abc2
[root@home1 ~]# usermod -G newgroup11 abc2
[root@home1 ~]# groups abc2
abc2 : abc2 newgroup11
[root@home1 ~]# usermod -G newgroup11 abc2
[root@home1 ~]# usermod -G abc2 abc2
[root@home1 ~]# groups abc2
abc2 : abc2
```

** Kindly correct me if I am wrong. **

Comment: This "works", but only because you have a single secondary group. `usermod -G newgroup11 abc2` will put you in the secondary group `newgroup11`. Since the primary group is `abc2`, you will end up in both groups. `usermod -g abc2 abc2` results in `newgroup11` being removed from the secondary groups *because* it is not mentioned anymore. So for three or more different groups, this method won't work. See the other answers involving `gpasswd` for a better command.

Answer (score -1):

To continue using usermod in a distro (like Fedora) which does not have a remove option, where user=bob and group=deletethisgroup, command would be:

```
usermod -G `cat /etc/group |  grep bob | grep -v deletethisgroup | cut -d ':' -f 1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'` bob
```

The pipes (1) get all group entries user belongs to, (2) take out the one which needs to be removed, (3) returns first column (group name), replaces newline with comma, and removes trailing comma.

Of course, you could put all that in a bash script which takes user and group to be deleted as parameters.  awk could be used to shorten the end but I wanted to stick to grep, cut,  tr and sed.

Comment: According to this [man page](http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora13/man1/gpasswd.1.html), `gpasswd -d bob deletethisgroup` is available too. Any reason why you are not using it?

Comment: Not everyone wants to set up group passwords.  I was just offering a solution using the command that was referenced by the question on a particular distro.  in Fedora/RHEL/Centos with gpasswd -d the removed user can still join the group if he has access to the password.  It actually increases group access as opposed to disallowing it.

Comment: I understood that the utility is named `gpasswd` because it is closely related to `/etc/passwd`, but instead manages groups. Unlike the plain `passwd` command which just controls passwords, `gpasswd` can also be used to manage membership of a group. A group password is not required if you are root or a group administrator.

Comment: Did you read the gpasswd manual?  For Fedora/RHEL/CentOS, if you read the manual, it is stated that the command "is used to administer /etc/group, and /etc/gshadow".  It actually has no effect on /etc/passwd.  Manual also states "Group passwords are an inherent security problem since more than one person is permitted to know the password."  It does not actually manage membership of a group, it opens the group up to ANY user with the password.  A group password is not required if you are already a MEMBER of the group.

Comment: Closely related was in the sense of similar naming and purposes, I did not imply that the /etc/passwd file is actually managed by gpasswd. Note that "man page" in my first comment points to the gpasswd manual page for Fedora 13. Using `gpasswd $group` you can set the group password which causes the security issue you mentioned. However you can also *not* have a password and use `gpasswd -d $user $group` to delete a user as described in the first comment and accepted answer. Note that this command does not prompt for a group password nor does it modify or require it.