# RHEL 7.5 - How to remove user from a group?

Tags: linux, rhel, users, group

`usermod` does not have an option to remove user from a group

```
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN

Options:
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
  -G, --groups GROUPS           new list of supplementary GROUPS
  -a, --append                  append the user to the supplemental GROUPS
                                mentioned by the -G option without removing
                                him/her from other groups
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -l, --login NEW_LOGIN         new value of the login name
  -L, --lock                    lock the user account
  -m, --move-home               move contents of the home directory to the
                                new location (use only with -d)
  -o, --non-unique              allow using duplicate (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       use encrypted password for the new password
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -s, --shell SHELL             new login shell for the user account
  -u, --uid UID                 new UID for the user account
  -U, --unlock                  unlock the user account
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     new SELinux user mapping for the user account
```

Which command & options are used to remove a user from a group?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29570/how-do-i-remove-a-user-from-a-group

Comment: @Panther Reviewed and used all the options used in that query. no luck

Comment: @Panther Which option from that query has to be used for removing the user from group? there are multiple different answers there.

Comment: @Panther I tried `usermod -G wheel appuser`, it did not remove `appuser` from `wheel`

Comment: @Panther Read this... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29570/how-do-i-remove-a-user-from-a-group#comment472498_29570 Those answers are not for RHEL

Answer (score 14):

The appropriate option is `-G`, but you don’t specify groups you want to remove, you specify groups you want to keep. If `user` is a member of `group1` and `group2`, you can remove `group2` by running

```
usermod -G group1 user
```

This will update `user` so that the only supplementary group membership is `group1`.

As mentioned in [How do I remove a user from a group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29570/86440), you can also use `gpasswd`:

```
gpasswd -d user group2
```

will remove `user` from `group2`.

Comment: and if a user is a member of 3 groups and you want to remove only 1 with `usermod` then the list of groups is coma-separated: `usermod -G group1,group2 user`